# Add decimal places with SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, decimal

I am on SQL Server 2008 R2 and I need to have 3 decimal places in 1 column of my table. The data type is float.
For example, I have

- 193,2
- 8223,36
- 2559,796

... that I would like to transform into

- 193,200
- 8223,360
- 2559,796

I tried with

- ROUND([MyValue], 3) --> It doesn't adds zeros for numbers that have less than 3 decimals
- FORMAT([MyValue],'######.000') --> 'FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.
- convert(nvarchar(10),[MyValue], '######.000') --> Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 3 of convert function (I also have this error message when I change nvarchar(10) into float)

Do you have an idea of how I could add these zeros ?

Comment: 193,2 isn't the same as 193,200? should the **,** be a **.** ?

Comment: @christiandev, this is likely a localization difference.  Some countries use `,` where others use `.` to indicate decimal.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use convert in addition to cast.

```
declare @MyValue decimal
set @MyValue = 193.2
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(10, 3), @MyValue)
```

The value returned is 193.200 (American formatting).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tested your suggestions for both CAST and CONVERT, but it didn't work (I don't get an error message, I have the expected number of rows affected, but when I refresh the table, I still have numbers with 1, or 2, or 3 decimals).

Here is exactly what I typed :

update [CUSTOM].[CustomSupplier]
set [MyValue] = CONVERT(decimal(10, 3), [MyValue])

Comment: What is the setup defined for the column MyValue?  If it's set to a decimal, for example, it holds the value just fine.

Comment: @brutzen, why would this cause an issue?

Comment: @user3820372 You don't seem to understand the difference between the number and its textual representation. You shouldn't care how the number is stored. If you do, you are doing something wrong. You should only care about zeros when you convert the number to string to present to the user. Put the `convert()` code in your query that returns the final result. Better yet, make the program that fetches this data format it as required.

Comment: The reason why I would like to change how the number is stored is because the data is shown to the user through a software interface where I cannot directly do changes on the textual representation. And if I convert the data to string, I won't be able to do calculations.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually have 193.2, you can use the following...

```
SELECT CAST(193.2 AS DECIMAL(16, 3))
```

This would give **193.200**.  The [Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187746.aspx) used a scale and precision to determine how many values are after and before the decimal point.

> (**precision**) The maximum total number of decimal digits that will be
>   stored, both to the left and to the right of the decimal point. The
>   precision must be a value from 1 through the maximum precision of 38.
>   The default precision is 18.
>
> (**scale**) The number of decimal digits
>   that will be stored to the right of the decimal point. This number is
>   substracted from p to determine the maximum number of digits to the
>   left of the decimal point. The maximum number of decimal digits that
>   can be stored to the right of the decimal point. Scale must be a value
>   from 0 through p. Scale can be specified only if precision is
>   specified. The default scale is 0; therefore, 0 <= s <= p. Maximum
>   storage sizes vary, based on the precision.

**EDIT**: Based on your comment on the other answer.

If you're going to use:

```
update [CUSTOM].[CustomSupplier] set [MyValue] = 
                             CONVERT(decimal(16, 3), [MyValue])
```

Make sure that `[MyValue]` is actually a `decimal`, or the update will not work.

Comment: Actually this works with a SELECT statement but not with my UPDATE statement. And I would like to modify the data itself in the table, not only the way it is presented.
I suspect that the problem comes from the fact that my column is calculated from 2 other columns where the number of decimals varies...

Comment: it is a float. Does it make a difference if I change it to decimal ?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL function you're looking for is [`STR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx):

```
STR([MyValue],10,3)    -- 10 characters with 2 decimal places.
```

However this is the job of the application (or reporting) layer, not the data layer - typically you leave the data coming from the data source as numbers (or dates) to allow other capabilities (sorting, filtering, etc) and let the display layer determine the proper format to present the data.

Answer (score 0):

On MS SQL Query, i think its hard to input on table when you have decimal with comma (,) separator. Its easier if you convert the data first to decimal with dot (.) separator. On this you can use CONVERT and replace (,) to (.)

```
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 3), REPLACE(REPLACE('193,2', '.', ''),',', '.')) AS [Converted];
```

Hope it can help someone

Answer (score 0):

Further to the answers above, yes this ONLY works if the nominator is also in the same format as the denominator.

To resolve this with WHOLE numbers, you have to cast the whole number as well.

```
CAST((CAST(1 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) / (SELECT count(*) AS vcount
                                  FROM   dbo.visitmanifests AS vm2
                                  WHERE  vm2.inactive = 0 AND vm2.visit_id = vm.Visit_ID)) AS DECIMAL(10, 2))
```